# c server handle multiple connections, error on port no

Tags: linux, centos, c

I've been experimenting with server code from http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.

The regular server code worked fine, I've changed it slightly to hardcode in a port number rather than read from the command line, but I wanted a server capable of holding multiple connections. It will be waiting for short strings to come in from 3 different client programs at regular intervals.

I've compiled the below but I'm getting the error "ERROR, no port provided", which makes no sense as I've definitely included the port number.

#### Some initial questions

- Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?
- Also, I hope no one minds me asking another question, could this be adapted to use multi-threading?

I'm using a dual core mini-processor with CentOS. It needs to read short amounts of data from a socket, which will be passed at regular intervals. I'm aware that forking could overload the cpu and but also that multi-threading may be too memory intensive also for this type of machine.

Are there any other alternatives for handling multiple socket connections that would be worth me researching? The data will come in every 5 seconds, every few hours, twice a day respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void read_socket(int); /* function prototype */
void error(const char *msg) 
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int store_limit=10; //user input
    int store_limit_secs=store_limit * 24 * 60 * 60; //user input
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
      portno = 15000;
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
         sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
          error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     while (1) {
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
         (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0)
         error("ERROR on accept");
     pid = fork();
     if (pid < 0)
         error("ERROR on fork");
     if (pid == 0)  {
         close(sockfd);
         read_socket(newsockfd);
         exit(0);
     }
     else close(newsockfd);
 } /* end of while */
 close(sockfd);
 return 0; /* we never get here */
}


void read_socket (int sock)
{ 
       int n;
       char buffer[256];
       bzero(buffer,256);
       n = read(sock,buffer,255);
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
       printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
       n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
}
```

Comment: "could this be adapted to use m" ... looks like you left off mid-word there.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of a command-line argument, `argc` will be `1`, so this block will execute, resulting the program exiting:

```
 if (argc < 2) {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
     exit(1);
 }
```

Since you hardcoded a value for `portno`, you can remove this block.

Comment: ah, god. I should have seen that! Thanks! I realise now I'd deleted that in my single server version before